# Undefined symbol rom external library with Swig/Python

Tags: python, redhat, swig

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877267/swig-python-undefined-symbol-error) but it doesn't seem to help my case.

I have a C++ library that I am wrapping parts of using SWIG (unfortunately swig 2.0).  This library performs some socket communications with a remote server and I need to make use of it from Python.  I am finally able to compile and link a .so file but during my testing, when importing the generated module, I get the following:

```
...
    _mod = imp.load_module('_YBB', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: ./_YBB.so: undefined symbol: _Z11IPV4Gatewayhhhh
```

This undefined symbol equates to:

```
IPV4Gateway(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)
```

This is frustrating as I don't have a call to this function anywhere in the wrapped library.  So it must be in the underlying socket library that I am calling.

Does anyone know what I have to do to clear up this undefined symbol?

Comment: Check whether *.c file related to missing function is compiled when you are building the library. To verify .so containing given symbol you can use techniques described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file

Comment: @amald, the problem is that the missing function isn't in the code I am wrapping at all.  It must be required by the underlying socket library somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind.  It turns out that it *was* declared in a header file but never implemented.  So swig (correctly) wrote a wrapper for it but was never able to link against the underlying implementation (which didn't exist).